# Updating the values in an array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rxjs

I am trying to merge two objects that I am getting from 2 different api calls(the example here is just a sample). How can I merge the UserId array of object and the userCredentials array together in the user state? I want the state to look like this user:[{id: 1, name"john", country="de"},{id: 2, name"micheal", country="us"}]

```
...
    import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //api call 1 receiving user Id and name
    const UserId = [{ id: 1, name: "john" }, { id: 2, name: "micheal" }];
    this.setState({ user: UserId });

    //api call 2 receiving userCredentials
    const userCredentials = [
      { id: 1, country: "de" },
      { id: 1, country: "us" }
    ];

    this.setState({
      user: { ...this.state.user, credentials: userCredentials }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("values", this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


...
```

my sample code is

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-water-5lzs1?file=/src/App.js:0-754

Comment: You can use array.concat(anotherArray) to merge two arrays together.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need to map thru 1 array and find if each object in the array exists in another array and use spread operator and return the merged object in map callback

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/object-merge-issue-fix-ntkxb)

**Use the code below:**

```js
    // option 1 - if you know the keys of the object
    let merged = UserId.map(u => {
      const user = userCredentials.find(uc => uc.id === u.id);
      if (user) u["country"] = user.country;
      return u;
    });

    // option 2 - generic merge
    let merged2 = UserId.map(u => {
      const user = userCredentials.find(uc => uc.id === u.id);
      if (user) return { ...u, ...user };
      return u;
    });
```

Comment: awesome... please consider to accept the answer if you like..

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'array.concat([])' to merge two array objects together. See bellow example.

```
let UserId = [{ id: 1, name: "john" }, { id: 2, name: "micheal" }];
const userCredentials = [{ id: 1, country: "de" },{ id: 1, country: "us" }];

const newArray = UserId.concat(userCredentials);
```

Since you have defined UserId as a const you cannot change it. So you have to make it to let or var to modify the variable.

Comment: concat will basically merge all of them together and I will have a separate object of usercredentials. But I  want to merge the credentials with the userId.

Comment: can you do this change in the sandbox as I tried and it returned me a state with 4 arrays

Comment: Do you want this [{id: 1, name: "john", country: "de"}] ?

Comment: If so, you have to use array.map to construct new object in an array. This is already answered by gdh.